# preform jira rest api search with maxresults parameter

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to preform a search using the Jira REST API and a JQL query but I don't want my results to be limited. So if there are 100 issues, 100 issues will appear on the result, if there are x issues, x issues will appear on the result.

How do I do this?

For example with this query:

```
https://"your_jira_gome"/rest/api/2/search?jql=project = "A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JIRA REST API Docs there's a maxResults URL parameter:

> maxResults
>
> int
>
> the maximum number of issues to return (defaults to 50). The maximum allowable value is dictated by the JIRA property 'jira.search.views.default.max'. If you specify a value that is higher than this number, your search results will be truncated.

Comment: I know, i have used this parameter the problem is that  to use it i have to know in advance the total number of issues that the search will return. 

for instance if there were x issues, and max results < x then i would have a problem...

is there any way to say i want all issues returned?

Comment: Why don't just always use a large number for maxResults, say 1000000? Of course, you should not forget about  'jira.search.views.default.max' property which is 1000 by default.

Comment: Or otherwise, execute the search with maxResults=1 and then examine 'total' property of the returned object - it'll contain an actual number of found  issues.

Comment: 'jira.search.views.default.max'  is a system JIRA property that limits maxResults. This means that if your search yields 2000 issues and you set maxResults to 2000, you will still get no more that 1000 issues with that property's default value.

Comment: Empty JQL query equals to 'all issues'.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've been an excellent help. 

just another thing, is there a way to get past the 'jira.search.views.default.max' ?? and get more then an eventual 1000 results?

Comment: I think not in a single query. But you may use paging by setting startAt URL parameter or adjust the value of the 'jira.search.views.default.max'  property as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-jira-configuration-126006.html

Comment: @Alex it can be maxResults=0 as well if you only care about the total.

Comment: If you have access to the server then you can set a privileged user group that will be able to bypass the limits by setting the _jira.search.views.max.unlimited.group_

Comment: @jannis you are correct but still it's better to use paging. Those limits are introduced for a reason.

Comment: Yes the limit is there for a reason and it shouldn't be worked around by either paging or setting high/no limits server side. Paging is also not a desirable solution. Normally an admin of a REST API would set a per-user request number/rate limit alongside the single-response row limit and sent a _429 Too Many Requests_ when abused.

Comment: @Alex BTW There's more relevant information in the comments than in the answer. You should consider updating your answer with the contents of this discussion.